# how set footer position permanently

Tags: html, css

Hi  all I have a problem :( I need to set the footer of a site
but i have problems with css3

The site is http://jobs.ejner69.net

the image on error is on this 
I have a resolution of 1650 x 1050

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lyxsf.jpg

How can fix that? for the footer show on bottom?

thanks..

Comment: the problem only show on high resolutions , in 1024 x 768 the footer shows correctly

Comment: the solution i provided below explains how to "push" the footer to the bottom, no matter what the page size or resolution is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with CSS Sticky Footer implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112082/problem-with-css-sticky-footer-implementation)

Answer (score 4):

I've been using this solution:

http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

For quite some time now. It's worked for all major/minor browsers, including mobile.

Comment: That solution has been hit-or-miss for me. The method at [http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) has always worked in my projects.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can see is that your body element has a limited height. There is not much that I, personally can do here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove overflow:hidden from the body. 
It causes half of the page to be hidden in my 16:9 monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I usually anchor the footer to the bottom of the page using `position:fixed;` and `bottom:0;`.