# How to set footer stick bottom if `.content` is `absolute`?

Tags: css

How to set footer stick bottom if `.content` is `absolute`?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9774272/1927742) and also another use same method adding padding bottom....  but it is not work if .content is set position absolute and top

*p.s I don't want to set footer fixed...*

Thanks.

```
.head{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 40px;
    height: 160px;
}
.content{
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
}
.footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
<body>
    <div class="head"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to use the solution presented in the answer you linked to, you have to stop using `position: absolute`. You can use margins to replace `top`:

```
.head {
    margin: 40px 0;
    height: 160px;
}
```

However, trying to use the sticky footer trick with this triggers an unfortunate property of CSS: if you have a margin on the first child element, that margin will propagate to the parent element. This causes problems with the sticky footer trick.

The solution to that is to use `padding` on the wrapper rather than `margin-top` on the header. Your code might then look like this:

```
.wrap {
    padding-top: 40px;
}
.head {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    height: 160px;
}
```

Having made those changes, the method described in the answer you linked to should work.

Comment: is there any other way to make sticky footer? because if use this method all  block within the container can't set position absolute or relative, top, height easily....

Comment: @vibskov: You can set `position: relative` on `.content` and all `position: absolute`s within `.content` will be relative to it.