# How to keep the footer at the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, footer

Here is my html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <head>
        <style>
            #foot {
               position:absolute;
               bottom:0;
               width:100%;
               height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
               background:#6cf;
            }

            .container{
                border: 1px solid RGB(100,100,100);
                -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
                -moz-border-radius: 10px;
                border-radius: 5px;
                height: 940px;
                width: 1200px;
                background: white;
                box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px;
                position: absolute;
                margin-left: 25px;
                margin-right: 20px;
                margin-top: 80px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Page</h1>
        <div class="container">
        </div>
        <footer id="foot">
            My footer
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

But this keeps the footer in between the page. Can some one help me out here?

Comment: [check this](http://www.cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with CSS Sticky Footer implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112082/problem-with-css-sticky-footer-implementation)

Comment: No. Its different as my div is causing all the problem. It works until I add my div. Is there any problem with my div?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use

```
position:fixed;
```

for the #foot

http://jsfiddle.net/q3U4R/

possibly a better way:

http://jsfiddle.net/q3U4R/1/

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; } 

html, body, #wrap { height: 100%; }

body > #wrap {height: auto; min-height: 100%;}

. container { padding-bottom: 150px; }  /* must be same height as the footer */

#foot { 
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 150px;
    clear:both;
    background:#ff0;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I dont want a fixed footer. I know I can do it that way. Is there anyway to keep it in bottom without making it fixed. Even if I change the content it should automatically go to bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
  <style>
    #foot {
      position:absolute;
      bottom:0;
      width:100%;
      height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
      background:#6cf;
    }

    #overlay {
      Z-INDEX: 9999; 
      POSITION: fixed; 
      TEXT-ALIGN: center; 
      WIDTH: 100%; BOTTOM: 0px; 
      HEIGHT: 80px; 
      _position: absolute
    }

    .container{
      border: 1px solid RGB(100,100,100);
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      height: 940px;
      width: 1200px;
      background: white;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px;
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: 25px;
      margin-right: 20px;
      margin-top: 80px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>My Page</h1>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
  <div id="overlay">
    <footer id="foot">
    My footer
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html></footer></div></h1></body></style></head>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your looking for. Press the button in my example to see how the footer is sticked to the bottom no matter how much content you put into your body. Hope this helps you out <3

```js
$("#add").on("click", function() {
  $("<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>").appendTo(".page-wrap");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -142px; 
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  height: 142px; 
}
.site-footer {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-wrap">
  
  <h1>Sticky Footer</h1>
  <h2>with Fixed Footer Height</h2>
  
  <button id="add">Add Content</button>  
     
</div>

<footer class="site-footer">
  I'm the Sticky Footer.
</footer>
```